# Scala: treat list of lists separately

Tags: scala, list

I have a list of type Order in scala.

`case class Order(id: String, prod: Product, quantity: Int)`

`case class Product(id: String, name: String, tasks: List[Task])`

I do this and I get a `List(List[Task]))`:

```
val listTaskLists = orders.map(p => p.getProduct().tasks)
```

Now I want to return a List of type TaskSchedule. The number of entries that this list will have is the size of listTaskLists times the quantity of each product.

For example, I have these entries:

```
val order1 = new Order("ORD_1", product1, 1) // product1 has 4 tasks
val order2 = new Order("ORD_2", product2, 2) // product2 has 6 tasks
val order3 = new Order("ORD_3", product3, 3) // product3 has 5 tasks
val order4 = new Order("ORD_4", product4, 1) // product4 has 5 tasks

val orders = o1 :: o2 :: o3 :: o4 :: Nil
```

Having this in consideration I should return a list of TaskSchedule with 36 entries: **(4 tasks * 1 prods) + (6 tasks * 2 prods) + (5 tasks * 3 prods) + (5 tasks * 1 prods) = 36 task schedules**

But I am not being able to do so. The closest I got was returning a list with 4 task schedules (the size of listTaskLists):

```
listTaskLists.map(s => new TaskSchedule(null, 1, 100 minute, 200 minute))
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's hard to be sure from your question if that's really what you are asking, but my guess is you are looking for `.flatMap`. Try doing `orders.flatMap` instead of `orders.map`, see if it gives you what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val orders = List(order1, order2, order3, order4) // List[Order]
               .map(ord => (ord.prod.tasks, ord.quantity)) // List[(List[Task], Int)]
               .flatMap(t => createSchedules(t._1.size * t._2)) // List[TaskSchedule]

def createSchedules(numSchedules: Int): List[TaskSchedule] =
  List.fill[TaskSchedule](numSchedules)(new TaskSchedule(null, 1, 100 minute, 200 minute))
```

**Edit**:
`orders` can be shortened to:

```
val orders = List(order1, order2, order3, order4)
               .flatMap(ord => createSchedules(ord))

def createSchedules(ord: Order): List[TaskSchedule] = {
  val numSchedules = ord.prod.tasks.size * ord.quantity
  List.fill[TaskSchedule](numSchedules)(new TaskSchedule(null, 1, 100 minute, 200 minute))
}
```

Comment: This helped me a lot, thank you. But I still have a question: what if I want `createSchedules` to have another parameter of type Order?
How can I send an order here: `.flatMap(t => createSchedules(t._1.size * t._2))`?
I wanted to do something like this: `.flatMap(t => createSchedules(t._1.size * t._2, orders(index)))`

Comment: Look at the edit I posted several minutes ago, in which an `order` is available in the `flatMap`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate over a list of things and have the resulting list be a different length, you can use a `fold`

```
// This says that we are folding over the orders list, and turning it into a list of TaskSchedules (starting with an empty list of them)
val taskSchedules = orders.foldLeft(List.empty[TaskSchedule]) { (taskSchedules, currentOrder) =>

  // This is where you put your logic for turning the currentOrder into a list of TaskSchedules
  val newSchedules: List[TaskSchedule] = ???

  // Add these new schedules to the existing ones
  taskSchedules ++ newSchedules
}
```